# useSelector does not rerender the component when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, state

I'm working on a news aggregator, and I have a `Newsfeed` component that maps through the relevant posts and creates a `Post` component for each one. There's a `Sidebar` component that shows the user the feeds they are subscribed to, and allows them to subscribe to new ones or unsubscribe from existing ones. What I'd like to happen is:

1. When a user adds a new feed, `Newsfeed` rerenders and now shows posts from the new feed.
2. When a user removes a feed, `Newsfeed` rerender and no longer shows posts from that particular feed.

As far as retrieving the correct posts - my backend takes care of that, and it works fine. The backend returns posts based on the feeds that the user is subscribed to. The problem is, when the user adds or removes a feed, the `Newsfeed` component does not rerender, and requires a page reload to show the updated feed. At the same time however, the Redux store IS updated, and I can see the state change every time via the Redux Dev Tools.

In `Newsfeed`, I'm using the `useSelector` hook to get a few different pieces of state, yet the component does not rerender when the state changes. I was under the impression that any component that used the `useSelector` hook would automatically be rerendered when that piece of state changed, but if that's not how the hook works then please correct me.

`Newsfeed.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import usePostFetch from "../hooks/usePostFetch";
import { Post } from "./Post";
import { Tag } from "./Tag";
import { Upvote } from "./Upvote";
import { getDate } from "../services/getDate";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { InitialState } from "../store/reducers/rootReducer";

export const Newsfeed = (props: any) => {

  const userState = useSelector((state: InitialState) => {
    return state.auth;
  });

  const { user } = userState;

  const publisherState = useSelector((state: InitialState) => {
    return state.publishers.publishers;
  });

  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  const { loading, error, posts, hasMore } = usePostFetch(pageNumber);

  const observer: any = useRef();
  const lastPostElementRef = useCallback(
    (node) => {
      if (loading) return;
      if (observer && observer.current) observer.current.disconnect();
      observer.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore) {
          console.log("Visible ");
          setPageNumber((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber + 1);
        }
      });
      if (node) observer.current.observe(node);
      console.log(node);
    },
    [loading, hasMore]
  );

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto bg-gray-900" id="newsfeed">
      <div className="object-center grid grid-cols-1 gap-8 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-5 mx-auto pb-6 pt-6">
        
        {posts.map((post, index) => {
          return (
            <Post
              key={post.id}
              title={post.title}
              url={post.url}
              image={post.image}
              category={post.category}
              postId={post._id}
              created={post.created}
              publisher={post.publisher}
              upvotes={post.upvotes}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div>{loading && "Loading..."}</div>
      <div>{error && "Error"}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`publisherActions.ts`: (Relevant parts)

```
export const removeFeed = (allFeeds: any, feedName: any, userId: any) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch<PublisherDispatchTypes>
) => {
  try {
    axios({
      method: "PUT",
      url: "users/removepublisher",
      params: { publisher: feedName, userId },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        let newAllFeeds = allFeeds.filter((feed: any) => {
          return feed.name.localeCompare(feedName) !== 0;
        });

        allFeeds = newAllFeeds;

        console.log(`Feed was removed, ${res}`);
        dispatch({
          type: REMOVE_FEED_SUCCESS,
          payload: allFeeds,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error removing feed, ${err}`);
        dispatch({
          type: REMOVE_FEED_FAILURE,
        });
      });
  } catch {
    dispatch({ type: REMOVE_FEED_FAILURE });
    console.log("Caught error while removing feed");
  }
};

export const addFeed = (allFeeds: any, feed: any, userId: any) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch<PublisherDispatchTypes>
) => {
  console.log("IN THE ADD_FEED FUNCTION");
  try {
    axios({
      method: "PUT",
      url: "users/addpublisher",
      params: { publisher: feed, userId },
    })
      .then((res) => {

        console.log(`Feed was added, ${res}`);
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_FEED_SUCCESS,
          payload: {
            name: feed.name,
            url: feed.url,
            image: feed.image,
          },
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error adding feed, ${err}`);
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_FEED_FAILURE,
        });
      });
  } catch {
    dispatch({ type: ADD_FEED_FAILURE });
    console.log("Caught error while adding feed");
  }
```

`publisherReducer.ts`: (Relevant parts)

```
import { Reducer } from "react";
import {
  PublisherDispatchTypes,
  REMOVE_FEED_SUCCESS,
  REMOVE_FEED_FAILURE,
  ADD_FEED_SUCCESS,
  ADD_FEED_FAILURE,
} from "../actions/publisherActionsTypes";
import { Publisher } from "../../../../shared/Publisher";

interface PublisherResponse {
  publishers: Publisher[];
}

export interface PublisherState {
  publishers: Publisher[] | undefined;
  loadedUsersFeeds: boolean;
  feedCount: number;
}

const defaultState: PublisherState = {
  publishers: undefined,
  loadedUsersFeeds: false,
  feedCount: 0,
};

const publisherReducer = (
  state: PublisherState = defaultState,
  action: PublisherDispatchTypes
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REMOVE_FEED_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        publishers: action.payload,
      };
    case REMOVE_FEED_FAILURE:
      return state;
    case ADD_FEED_SUCCESS:
      let pubs = state.publishers || [];
      return {
        ...state,
        publishers: [...pubs, action.payload],
      };
    case ADD_FEED_FAILURE:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default publisherReducer;
```

Comment: there is no reducer for REMOVE_FEED_SUCCESS

Comment: @HMR I actually do have that, I've edited the post.

Comment: You need to call `useEffect()` and track the subscription state inside of it. For example `useEffect(callArticleReducer, [subscriptionState])`. Read more on [useEffect here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: I've tried adding a `useEffect()` hook and adding `publishers` to the dependency array, no go. I thought the hook would force the component to rerender every time `publishers` updated, but so far it hasn't worked.

Comment: Why not use `{ publisher: feedName, userId }` to filter feeds in the reducer? I don't see why you would complicate things the way you do it and having to pass allfeeds in the action but I also have no idea what your code looks like calling the action. I assume providing the unique id of the feed to remove is enough.

Comment: You're correct that the `useSelector` hook will re-render the component when the extracted data changes.  The logic in the thunk and reducer seem correct as far as I can see, so there must be something else going on.  As a side note, you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) to write your Redux logic - it will drastically simplify what you've got here.

Comment: @HMR You're right, I don't need to send all the publishers in order to remove a feed - that's something I forgot to clean up when I was refactoring the reducer. I'll remove that now. Still doesn't explain why the component does not rerender.

Comment: @markerikson I'll definitely try it out, thanks for mentioning.